# Android Studio: How do you make a method when pressing a button with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've tried making the below method for a button on Android Studio, and when I run, the app crashes.

```
MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val button = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
    var count = 0
    val textView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener{
            buttonAction()
        }
    }

    fun buttonAction(){
        count = count+1
        textView.text = count.toString()
    }
}
```

I am well aware that in order for the button to work, you need to put stuff into the "button.setOnClickListener" part (see below). However, I want to make sure that my code is as neat and clean as possible by calling the method inside the "button.setOnClickListener" rather than put every stuff into that part.

```
MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        var count = 0
        val textView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView

        button.setOnClickListener{
            count = count+1
            textView.text = count.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any fixes for the 1st code, or would I have to settle for the 2nd code?

Comment: You should go with 2nd because you cant initial and add widgets id before setContentView() you should use widget id after this function

Comment: check answer for your 1 code few changes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var count = 0
    private var button: Button? = null
    private var textView: TextView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        button?.setOnClickListener {
            buttonAction()
        }
    }

    private fun buttonAction() {
        count += 1
        textView?.text = count.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: textView is in the wrong place

Comment: the textView variable (line 5, if that's what you're referring to) might be in the wrong place, but at least it's declared null before the onCreate method so therefore there shouldn't be any issues

Comment: @24_ned null is not a issue its good to initialize as a professional dev for the null exception .Please go through this link for more details-https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-kotlin-initialization-with-android-custom-views-cde06e915e8d

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your app crash is that you're trying to assign views(button and textView) that do not (yet) exist by calling them before `onCreate`.

```
val button = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
val textView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { ...
```

Just put this lines inside `onCreate` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

You can think of it as trying to shake your friend's hand before meeting him.

And about making code clean, I wouldn't worry about it too much, your second solution is good enough for a beginner.

Not sure if you're aware of [Android Basics in Kotlin course](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course), but it can help you a lot if you follow it step by step.

And just to give you an answer, here is a code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var count = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val button = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
    val textView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView

    button.setOnClickListener{
        buttonAction()
        textView.text = count.toString()
    }
}

fun buttonAction(){
    count += 1
   }
}
```

It's not the smoothest solution, but as i said, it's good enough